# Word, phrase or idiom for enforced charity?

Tags: vocabulary

Like when you must pay for a plastic carry bag for your shopping in a superstore but it all goes to charity. Little contrived inconveniences designed to extract money from you. There must be a specific term to capture this phenomenon of soft enforcement?

Comment: The example does not sound to me like 'enforcement'. It is not a system with which I am familiar but presumably one has the option of buying or not buying the plastic bag.  Is it that the shop refuses to wrap the goods, other than in a charity bag? The German system of church tithes, to which mplungian indirectly refers below, fits more obviously the notion of 'enforced charity'. Though I've no doubt some would argue that it is just an extension of taxation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Tithe* is an excellent suggestion. Another alternative is [***earning to give***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earning_to_give).

***tzedaka(h)*** is a Jewish term for obligatory charity.

***zakat*** is a complementary Islamic term.

Answer (score 4):

[Tithe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tithe) comes to mind

> A tithe (/ˈtaɪð/; from Old English: teogoþa "tenth") is a one-tenth part of something, paid as a contribution to a religious organization or compulsory tax to government. Today, tithes are normally voluntary and paid in cash, cheques, or stocks, whereas historically tithes were required and paid in kind, such as agricultural products. Several European countries operate a formal process linked to the tax system allowing some churches to assess tithes.

Other suggestions could be

[Alternative giving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_giving) or 
[Pay it forward](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pay_it_forward)

Comment: I would say that the religious connotation associated with *tithe* would mean it is inappropriate for this type of general usage. I'm not saying you're wrong, just that if my grocery store were trying to tithe me, I would find it odd.

Comment: A little further down in the Wikipedia article is a description of the Jewish (yes again religious but still) practice of ma'aser kesafim (tithing 10% of their income to charity) - it is possible to amend the connotations of the word :)

Answer (score 1):

I have sometimes seen "suggested contribution", or "recommended donation" used for this.

An example would be that in the UK, (at least in London) the museums are free for anyone who desires to go in. However, they have a 'suggested contribution' for each museum that is about what you would expect to pay for the price of a ticket.

It's not enforced per se, but they do have many signs and donation boxes where they have signs bearing language like 'suggested donation' or 'suggested contribution'.